# using pickle to write a list of lists

Tags: python, file, pickle

I tried to write a list of lists using pickle

```
import pickle
pkl_file=('lol.txt','wb')
listoflist=[[1,2],[3,4],[5.6]]
pickle.dump(listoflist,pkl_file)
```

but got the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lol.py", line 4, in <module>
pickle.dump(lol,pkl_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 203, in __init__
self.write = file.write
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I need to know what is wrong with this, or is there any other efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `pkl_file = open('lol.txt','wb')` instead of `('lol.txt','wb')`.

Comment: sorry that was a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

This error message:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'
```

is because:

```
pkl_file=('lol.txt','wb')
```

isn't what you intended to do. You've made a tuple of two strings.
Change that to:

```
pkl_file = open('lol.txt','wb')
```